# Batch install RPM packages from .tar.gz file on CentOS

Tags: linux, docker, centos, tar, rpm

How can I install a large group of .rpm packages that are compressed in a .tar.gz file?

Context: I am using Docker to build a CentOS 7 container and was provided a .tar.gz file containing many .rpm packages.  These packages are dependencies for a program I would be running within the container.  I would like a way to install all of these packages without needing to install them one by one (untar and 'rpm -ivh pkg1.rpm pkg2.rpm ...').

Comment: Maybe 'rpm -ivh *.rpm' would be an option after untar'ing... But is there a way to do this without needing to untar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to untar the file and the install them with rpm

```
tar xfz file.tar.gz
rpm -i *rpm
```

There is no way for rpm to install RPMs from standard input.

Otherwise there is a [archivemount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivemount) to mount the tarball (see https://superuser.com/questions/265772/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-tar-file).

Comment: Use `-U` instead of `-i` it is virtually **always** what you want or, even better, don't use `rpm` at all and use `yum install` instead.